# Django migrate value invalid literal

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-rest-framework

I have problem with Django migrate function.
I was trying to add new field to my user model and it looks like this.

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    """ Model to represent additional information about user """
    user = models.OneToOneField(
        User,
        on_delete=models.CASCADE,
        related_name='profile'
    )
    bio = models.TextField(
        max_length=2000,
        blank=True,
        default=''
    )
    # we use URL instead of imagefield because we'll use 3rd party img hosting later on
    avatar = models.URLField(default='', blank=True)
    status = models.CharField(max_length=16, default='', blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, default='')
    balance = models.BigIntegerField(default='0')

    def __str__(self):
        return self.user.username
```

balance is new what I added, and after that I'm receving messages like

> Operations to perform:   Apply all migrations: accounts, admin, auth,
>   authtoken, contenttypes, forums, posts, sessions, threads Running
>   migrations:   Applying accounts.0005_userprofile_balance...Traceback
>   (most recent call last):   File "manage.py", line 15, in 
>       execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 371, in execute_from_command_line
>       utility.execute()   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management__init__.py",
>   line 365, in execute
>       self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
>       self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\base.py", line 335, in execute
>       output = self.handle(*args, **options)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\commands\migrate.py",
>   line 200, in handle
>       fake_initial=fake_initial,   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 117, in migrate
>       state = self._migrate_all_forwards(state, plan, full_plan, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 147, in _migrate_all_forwards
>       state = self.apply_migration(state, migration, fake=fake, fake_initial=fake_initial)   File
>   "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\executor.py",
>   line 244, in apply_migration
>       state = migration.apply(state, schema_editor)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\migration.py",
>   line 122, in apply
>       operation.database_forwards(self.app_label, schema_editor, old_state, project_state)   File
>   "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\migrations\operations\fields.py",
>   line 84, in database_forwards
>       field,   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
>   line 315, in add_field
>       self._remake_table(model, create_field=field)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\sqlite3\schema.py",
>   line 187, in _remake_table
>       self.effective_default(create_field)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\backends\base\schema.py",
>   line 240, in effective_default
>       default = field.get_db_prep_save(default, self.connection)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 767, in get_db_prep_save
>       return self.get_db_prep_value(value, connection=connection, prepared=False)   File
>   "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 762, in get_db_prep_value
>       value = self.get_prep_value(value)   File "C:\Users\Rade\Desktop\rengorum-master\backend\env\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\fields__init__.py",
>   line 1826, in get_prep_value
>       return int(value) ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''

after I received that message, I tried to set default value to 0.00, but it's still same message, I deleted balance field and still receiving same message.
Any ideas?

Comment: I know that default='0' is not correct, but still same message without ''

Comment: did you tried it without declaring any field option ? just simply `balance = models.BigIntegerField()`

Answer (score 1):

This is basically a migration issue, as the migration files are generated based on your initial codes and when migrating, these migration files are being executed and throwing errors.

I think you can use either one of the following solution to fix it:

### Solution One

First you should delete the migration file(ie `0003_auto_<some id>.py`) inside `<app>/migrations` directory which was created when you ran `python manage.py makemigrations`. If you are unsure about which one to delete, then check the `django_migrations` table in your database and see till which migrations it has been applied. After removing the last migration file(or files), you need to change the default value to `0`. Then you should run makemigrations and migrate commands.

### Solution Two

Change the default value to `0` in models. Then change the migration file which has been created when you added the Field in model, like this:

```
    operations = [
        migrations.AddField(
            model_name='userprofile',
            name='balance',
            field=models.BigIntegerField(default=0),  # instead of default='0'
        ),
```

Also you should remove the additional migration files(if they are generated) when you fixed the default value and re ran the migration commands.

Answer (score 0):

BigIntegerField default value needs to be a whole number and not in quotes:

```
balance = models.BigIntegerField(default=0)
```

alternatively, if you need decimals:

```
balance = models.DecimalField(max_digits=6, decimal_places=2, default=0)
```

or use MoneyField https://github.com/django-money/django-money